# Email marketing in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, notifications

I have a site with articles which has an RSS feeds.
I 'd like visitors to be able to subscribe to those articles using their email.
They ll give their email and then new articles will be sent to their email.

I m using feedburner to email right now, but I dont like it at all.

How this can be done in using Drupal modules and an SMTP server?

What technology is stackexchange.com using for the email notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Messaging](http://drupal.org/project/messaging) and [Notifications](http://drupal.org/project/notifications) framework.

Comment: How do you compare those modules with http://drupal.org/project/simplenews ?

Comment: simplenews is really for only sending newsletters or custom admin messages to subscribed users. With the messaging and notifications framework, users can subscribe themselves to new content and automatically be notified by the site. It is a bit more complex to set up but contains much more features than i have explained.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a module for an [SMTP Email Relay Service Elastic Email](http://elasticemail.com): [Elastic Email](http://drupal.org/project/elastic_email).