# Simplenews automatically send out email notifications when new content is published

Tags: 7, notifications

I'm trying to figure out a way to allow anonymous users to subscribe to my blog and receive email updates whenever I publish new content.

I've tried a couple of solutions, but none of them seem to work the way I would like them to. This page (http://drupal.org/node/983184) says that I should be able to use Simplenews to do it, but I can't figure out how.

That module seems to be based around creating a Newsletter content node and which gets sent to the subscribers. However, what I want to do is post a new Article and have the system automatically send an email to all my subscribers containing something like a Teaser.

At the least, I'd like to send a simple email with the Content Title and a link to the node.

How do I configure Simplenews to work like this?

Comment: Check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41005/how-can-i-allow-users-to-receive-e-mails-whenever-i-update-my-blog-in-drupal-7/41472#41472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend to try the [Newsletter](http://drupal.org/project/newsletter) module. [This](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18871/which-newsletter-module-will-fit-my-requirements) may also help you.
[This](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4520/email-marketing-in-drupal-7) may also be another solution for you.

Comment: Can you point me to a good tutorial? I've got it installed, but I can't seem to figure out how properly to use it. When I try to create a List it needs me to choose a Template, but no templates are listed.

Comment: @KennyWyland: please check http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4520/email-marketing-in-drupal-7. Messaging and Notifications may help you.